# Shopify API Access scopes

Tags: shopify-app, scopes

I need a `read_draft_orders` and `write_draft_orders` permission after my app is approved by Shopify. right now when I training to install an app that time Shopify gives me an error like - Oauth error missing_shopify_permission: read_draft_orders, write_draft_orders. my question is how can I take a grant from Shopify after the app is approved by Shopify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a public app.
You just have to update your app with the permission scopes and reinstall the app on any store.